# Bulk Update DB2 using Hibernate and Multi Threading

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, db2

I have a requirement to update more than 1000000 records in DB2 database.
I tried using hibernate with multi threaded application updating the records. However, on doing so I was getting lockacquisitionexception. I feel it's because of the bulk commits I am doing along with multiple threads.
Can someone recommend a better solution or better way to do so.
Please let me know if I need to upload the code I am using.
Thanks in advance.

```
//Code running multiple times with threads 
Transaction tx = null; 
tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
for(EncryptRef abc : arList) { 
String encrypted = keyUtils.encrypt(abc.getNumber()); //to encrypt some data
Object o = session.load(EncryptRef.class,new Long(abc.getId())); //primary key EncryptRef object = (EncryptRef)o; 
object.setEncryptedNumber(encrypted); //updating the row 
} 
tx.commit(); //bulk commiting the updates
```

Table contains just three columns. ID|PlainText|EncryptedText

Update:
I tried batch updates using JDBC prepared statemenets. However, I am still facing the below exception:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException:
>   [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.63.75] Batch failure.  The batch was
>   submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member
>   of the batch. Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for
>   specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:407)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.n.a(n.java:386)    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.a(zn.java:4897)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.c(zn.java:4528)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.executeBatch(zn.java:2837)  at
>   org.npci.ThreadClass.run(ThreadClass.java:63)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Below is the code executed with batch size of 50-100 records:

```
String queryToUpdate = "UPDATE INST1.ENCRYPT_REF SET ENCR_NUM=? WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement pstmtForUpdate = conn.prepareStatement(queryToUpdate);
            for (Map.Entry<Long,String> entry : encryptMap.entrySet()) {
                pstmtForUpdate.setString(1, entry.getValue());
                pstmtForUpdate.setLong(2, entry.getKey());
                pstmtForUpdate.addBatch();
            }
            pstmtForUpdate.executeBatch();
            conn.close();
```

Comment: It's probably better to describe the update logic you use, and specify if you are able to do this inside a single transaction (you must have an appropriate transaction log size).

Comment: Additionally you should describe the operational requirements. Specifically, the concurrency requirements when your bulk update will run. Ensure that the UPDATE (or MERGE) statement(s) generated by Hibernate are *indexed*, and a suitable isolation-level is used. If the column(s) being updated are either indexed, or are foreign-keys, or have triggers then different advice may apply. SO: your question is too vague to get a specific answer.

Comment: When you run this code, does Hibernate select out the row first, before updating it? (Turn on SQL logging if you haven’t already.) You aren’t actually accessing any fields from the object so no need to read it. In general Hibernate is a poor way to do these kinds of updates; you’re better off just using SQL.

Comment: I tried JDBC prepared statement also. But no luck. Updated the code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your database structure it’s hard to recommend a specific solution. If you can change the database, a good strategy would be to partition your table and then arrange for each thread to update a separate partition. Instead of having multiple threads updating one large database and conflicting with each other, you would effectively have each thread each updating its own smaller database.

You should also make sure you’re effectively batching updates and not committing too often.

If your table has tons of indexes, it might be more efficient to drop some/all and rebuild after your update than to update then on an ongoing basis. Similarly you might consider removing triggers, referential integrity constraints, etc., then patching up later.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question. Used for better formatting.

To catch the actual db2 SQLCODE use the following technique. Otherwise it's impossible to understand the root cause of the problem.

```
try {
  ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    while (ex != null) {
        if (ex instanceof com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable) {
            com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable db2ex = 
        (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable) ex;
            com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Sqlca sqlca = db2ex.getSqlca();
            if (sqlca != null) {
              System.out.println("SQLCODE: " + sqlca.getSqlCode());
              System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + sqlca.getMessage());
            } else {
            System.out.println("Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error msg : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
        System.out.println("Error code (no db2): " + ex.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error msg  (no db2): " + ex.getMessage());
      }
        ex = ex.getNextException();
    }
    ...
}
```

As for ENCR_NUM field.
Is it possible to have actual values for this column outside of your application?
Or are such values can be generated by your application only?

Do you have to update all the table rows or is there some condition on the set of IDs which need to be updated?

Comment: We can generate the ENCR_NUM field outside the application too. We need to update this value for specific IDs. The concern is more than 1000000 that needs to be updated in less time and this is the reason I want to use multi threading.

Comment: So, why don't you want just to use a single statement like `UPDATE INST1.ENCRYPT_REF SET ENCR_NUM=<some_expression> WHERE ID <some_condition>`? What's the error you get using this?

Comment: I am fine with doing this. The concern is to load so many records and with minimum amount of time. If I try multi threading, it is resulting in locking the table.

Comment: It's hard to believe that you can do this faster even with multiple simultaneous connections doing single row updates in comparison to such a single `update` statement. The only concern is that such a single `update` may consume to much log space for your system.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to update so many records in DB2 in less time.

Comment: `insert into INST1.ENCRYPT_REF_NEW select ... from INST1.ENCRYPT_REF ...` should work faster especially if you switch off logging for the new table. You can drop the old table and rename the new one afterwards.